# Is there a more elegant way of raising error in Python?[specific case]

Tags: python, error-handling, coding-style

I'm totally new to Python and programming in general, so I'm not too familiar with good practices or writing my code in a most sufficient / clear way. I've written this function for some math operations and I want Python to handle some exceptions.

```
def sqrt_of_sum_by_product(numbers: tuple) -> float:
        if prod(numbers) <= 0:  # checking if the result is a positive num to prevent further operations
            raise ValueError('cannot find sqrt of a negative number or divide by 0')
        return float("{:.3f}".format(math.sqrt(sum(numbers) / prod(numbers))))
```

This code works and I think it's clear enough, but I'm not sure if raising exception like I did is a good practise, and I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Where does your `prod` come from?

Comment: You refuse to compute the result for `(1, -2)` for no good reason. I wouldn't call that "This code works".

Comment: @HeapOverflow ... while attempting to compute the result for `(-1, -1)`

Comment: @HeapOverflow I'm refusing to compute the result for (1, -2) because the product is a negative number, do you wouldn't want to look for a square root (and I'm not including complex numbers)
Or have I overlooked something?

Comment: @alaniwi `prod` comes from numpy module; that's just a small part of a bigger program, so I didn't include the whole code.

Comment: @SylwiaLeung But the sum is also negative, so the fraction is *positive* and you can take the square root without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's a good practice, but sometimes you may want to create your own errors.
For example :

```
class MyExeption(Exception):
    _code = None
    _message = None
    def __init__(self, message=None, code=None):
        self._code = message
        self._message = code
```

And now you can do :

```
def sqrt_of_sum_by_product(numbers: tuple) -> float:
        if prod(numbers) <= 0:  # checking if the result is a positive num to prevent further operations
            raise MyExeption('cannot find sqrt of a negative number or divide by 0', 'XXX')
        return float("{:.3f}".format(math.sqrt(sum(numbers) / prod(numbers))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that raising exceptions in this way is good practice. You can also use try/except to actually get an exception, and then handle it. I will not question your uses of the code.

Comment: Do you mean that the code itself is inefficient? As I wrote, I'm a total noob and I might have overlooked things that seem obvious. 
Thanks for help!